# How do I implement drag and drop in the Ace editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have an ["ace editor"](http://ace.ajax.org/) and a palette of thumbnail images. My customer would like to drag these thumbnails onto the editor and have some text inserted at the drop location, the url to a full-size image for example. However, I'm at a loss for finding a drop event anywhere in the API.

Is there a way to do this within the Ace API?

If not, is a reasonable solution to bind my own javascript function to mouse events that will insert text from a data attribute in the source (the dragged) element? If there are any examples out there, I haven't found them here or via Google.

Answer (score 0):

looks like there are no drag events emitted https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mouse/dragdrop.js#L99
you can either add your own drop listener or better set text from dragstart listener

```
imageContainer.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    // find image data from e.target
    e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", imageText);
})
```

Comment: Here's a basic example using the dragstart listener: https://plnkr.co/edit/Gv6pN3oJBj17906PKcZX?p=preview